# Grails Enabling automatic migrations (Grails 2.2.2)

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I'm testing Grails as a potential framework for our workplace. I'm using this tutorial found on Grails website to manage databases:

http://grails.github.io/grails-howtos/en/manageDatabases.html

I have been able to follow steps successfully all the way upto:

**Enabling automatic migrations**

After which if I restart the server using grails run-app I get a long error message starting with:

```
Error 2013-06-13 12:03:39,639 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader - Error initializing the application: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set 2012-02-01-initial-database.groovy::1371149615719-2::jable (generated):

Error: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE BOOK DROP COLUMN VERSION: Cannot
drop last column "VERSION"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE BOOK DROP COLUMN VERSION [90084-164]
Message: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE BOOK DROP COLUMN VERSION: Cannot drop last column "VERSION"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE BOOK DROP COLUMN VERSION [90084-164]
```

....and on and on....

any idea why?

Comment: It looks like you trying to drop and create database when use run-app command. Check your DataSource.groovy,environments->development->dataSource->dbCreate. Is value = "update"?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988514/what-is-a-good-workflow-for-database-migration-in-grails and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855484/how-do-we-migrate-update-the-database-schema-in-grails